# django can't drop the test DB via pgbouncer

Tags: django, postgresql, pgbouncer

I'm using pgbouncer with Django. I've added `test_foo` database to its config to be able to run tests, because apparently Django can't use a different port for the test DB. Now the test run but at the end, when Django tries to drop the test DB, I receive

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: database "test_foo" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There are 1 other session(s) using the database.
```

I suppose that is caused by the open connection stored by pgbouncer. What can I do?

Comment: This is such a frustrating problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not the perfect solution, but it does the trick. You can force Django to use different database settings when running unit tests by adding to your settings.py:

```
if 'test' in sys.argv or 'test_coverage' in sys.argv:    
    # Use 5432 as db port (avoid going through pgbouncer, can't delete test DB).
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
            'NAME': 'xxx',
            'USER': 'xxx',
            'PASSWORD': 'xxx',
            'HOST': '',
            'PORT': '5432'
        },
    }
```

Comment: great answer, works fine.  Small tweak: write the code like this to just change port number, assuming this is after your normal DATABASES setting: `if 'test' in sys.argv or 'test_coverage' in sys.argv:
    DATABASES['default']['PORT'] = 5432`